# Is there a tool to verify that the metadata of my NFT is correct?

Tags: tokens, nft, polygon, meta-data, contracturi

I am creating a collection of NFTs and I want to test that the metadata and the media files are correct. I am setting `tokenURI` on chain. How can I do this? I am using Polygon Mumbai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your NFT collection contract follows the `[IERC721 interface][1]`,
when you mint or transfer, OpenSea will listen to the events and show the collection on the OpenSea testnet, your collection can be found at:
`https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/mumbai/YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS`. You can then check if the NFT is displayed correctly.

Hope it helps